# SqlAlchemy with list in where clause

Tags: python, list, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, bindparam

my table in a database  is as follow

```
Username    city        Type 
 Anna       Paris        abc 
 Marc       london       abc
 erica      rome         AF 
 Sara       Newyork      cbd 
 silvia      paris        AD
```

I have a list contains string values

```
typelist = {'abc', 'cbd'}
```

and i want to query my database using sqlalchemy , to get  data from a table  where a column type equals the values in the list :

```
Username    city        Type 
 Anna       Paris        abc 
 Marc       london       abc
 Sara       Newyork      cbd
```

im trying this code

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data IN :values" 
query = sqlalchemy.text(sql).bindparams(values=tuple(typelist))
conn.engine.execute(query)
```

but it return just one value from the typelist not all the list values .

```
Username    city        Type 
 Sara       Newyork      cbd
```

Comment: What's your code of reading values from engine.execute? maybe you read only the first value from returning cursor

Answer (score 6):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data IN :values" 
query = sqlalchemy.text(sql).bindparams(sqlalchemy.bindparam("values", expanding=True))
conn.engine.execute(query, {"values": typelist})
```

Reference: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding

Answer (score -2):

My solution will work but you will need to format your string like this

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data IN ('data1', 'data2', 'data3')"
```

No need to use bind param here. Use this if you dont get any proper solution

Comment: firstly , i don't know the values in the list because its changed every hour , secondly,  i have a lot of values , this solution will dosent work

Comment: use @inf581 answer. it works best

Answer (score -2):

You could use a dynamic SQL approach where you create a string from your list values and add the string to your SELECT statement.

```
queryList = ['abc', 'def']


def list_to_string(inList):
    strTemp = """'"""
    for x in inList:
        strTemp += str(x) + """','"""
    return strTemp[:-2]

sql = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE data in (""" + list_to_string(queryList) + """)"""

print(sql)
```

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. This is the road to SQL injection.